# C# Property Syntax this[]

Tags: c#, properties

While searching for C#'s equivalent to Java's Hashmap, I came across a sliver of code that I've never seen before. Was hoping someone could explain the **signature** of the property definition in this class.

```
public class NullableDictionnary : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    string null_value;


    public StringDictionary this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (key == null) 
            {
                return null_value;
            }
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                null_value = value;
            }
            else 
            {
            base[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, what is meant by `this[string key]` ?

Comment: This is called an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: This could be hard to search on google, You can use http://symbolhound.com/ to search, look at the [result](http://symbolhound.com/?q=this%5Bstring+key%5D+C%23) for `this[string key] C#`

Answer (score 5):

That is called indexer. You can read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

Basically that allows you to access your elements with an index.So in this case you can acess your `NullableDictionnary` elements like this:

```
NullableDictionnary[key]
```

`key` should be a `string` because your class inherits from `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Normally if you pass a null key to an indexer of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you will get an `ArgumentNullException`.But here you are extending this indexer and returning a default value when the key passed as *null*.For example this will throw `ArgumentNullException`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Console.WriteLine(dict[null]); // ArgumentNullException
```

But this will not:

```
 var dict = new NullableDictionnary();
 Console.WriteLine(dict[null]);
```

That will write value of `null_value` variable.And a last note, you should change returning type of indexer to `string` instead of `StringDictionary` otherwise it won't compile.

```
 public string this[string key]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an indexer property.  Essentially providing implementation of [] operator.  More at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)